# Как создать локальную сеть через Python?

Tags: python, сервер, flask

Есть задача отправить документ с сервера на печать в принтер, подключенный к компьютеру клиента в обход ОС клиента. Как я понимаю, для этого нужно, чтобы сервер и клиент находились в одной локальной сети, чтобы был общий доступ к целевому принтеру. Вопрос в том, как такое соединение установить между клиентом и сервером, работающим на Python Flask?

Comment: Чтобы сервер на flask был доступен другому компьютеру в сети (локальной или интернет) нужно в `app.run` заполнить `host="0.0.0.0"` ([пример](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/2a81e23d21e4ba9754e5b8f465950f10d93cb4ec/webserver__handler_key_mouse_click_and_move/main.py#L183)), а клиенту указывать ip сервера и порт. Если это происходит в локальной сети, то ip сервера можно узнать из ipconfig из поля *IPv4-адрес*, еще стоит не забывать, что помешать подключению могут настройки сети (типа частная или общественная) и брандмаузер

Comment: `в обход ОС клиента.` - это как? какая ос у клиента?

Comment: у клиента windows, но нужно, чтобы документ выходил на печать в нужный принтер для того, чтобы предотвратить утечку данных. Т.к. существует принтер Microsoft to PDF, через который можно сохранить файл на машине пользователя.